# UITableView subclass not executing past init

Tags: ios, uitableview, init

I'm building an application which uses a programmatically generated `UITableView` to pop-up and populate a `UITextField`. When the user touches the `UITextField` a TableView of valid values should pop up. The `UITableView` has sections and a search bar. I took the code from another very similar app I have written, where it works fine.

When the `UITextField` is touched, executing starts in the `UITableView` (`CatagoryTableViewController.m`), but only the init method is called, and then control returns to the calling class (`ViewController.m`). I've overridden the key popup for the UITextField.

There is a XIB for **`ViewController`** but not for **`CatagoryTableViewController`**. The UITextField Touch Down is mapped to the **`catagoryFieldPressed`** method.

By the way, SFCLog is defined as:

```
define SFCLog(FORMAT, ...) fprintf(stderr,"%s [line %d] %s\n",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__,[[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__]  UTF8String])
```

I have placed SFCLog logs (a variation of NSLog) at the start of every method in `CatagoryTableViewController`, and only init is ever called. Any ideas on what I am missing?

**From `ViewController.h`** (Calling class header)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    Word *currentWord;
    NSMutableArray *words;
    int wordsIndex;
    int viewState;
    int correctCounter;
    int incorrectCounter;
}
```

**From `ViewController.m`** (Calling class)

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    SFCLog(@"");
    return NO;  // Hide both keyboard and blinking cursor.
}

- (IBAction)catagoryFieldPressed:(id)sender
{
    SFCLog(@"Catagory button");
    CatagoryTableViewController *childView = [[CatagoryTableViewController alloc] init];
    childView.parentView = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES];
    SFCLog(@"Returned from Catagory button");
}
```

**`CatagoryTableViewController.h`**

```
@class ViewController;

@interface CatagoryTableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate> 
{
    NSMutableDictionary *catagoryDictionary;
    NSArray *filteredArray;
    UISearchBar *searchBar;
    UISearchDisplayController *searchController;
    NSMutableArray *sectionArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) ViewController *parentView;
```

**`CatagoryTableViewController.m`** Much more code than this, but these methods should fire.

```
@implementation CatagoryTableViewController
@synthesize parentView;


- (id) init
{
    SFCLog(@"");
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        SFCLog(@"in here");        
    }
    SFCLog(@"");
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    SFCLog(@"");
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)loadView
{
    SFCLog(@"load view");
    [super loadView];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;

    // Load the catagory dictionary from the database
    WordService *wordService = [[WordService alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *rawCatagories = [wordService getCatagories];
    catagoryDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (WordCatagory *wordCatagory in rawCatagories) {
        [catagoryDictionary setObject:wordCatagory forKey:wordCatagory.wordCatagory];
    }

    // Section Array
    sectionArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        [sectionArray addObject:[self itemsInSection:i]];
    SFCLog(@"sectionArray: %@",sectionArray);


    // Create a search bar
    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)];
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    // Create the search display controller
    searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;   
}
```

**Debug Console output**

```
 [ViewController catagoryFieldPressed:] [line 223] Catagory button
 [CatagoryTableViewController init] [line 18] 
 [CatagoryTableViewController init] [line 21] in here
 [CatagoryTableViewController init] [line 23] 
 [ViewController catagoryFieldPressed:] [line 227] Returned from Catagory button
 [ViewController textFieldShouldBeginEditing:] [line 33]
```

**Edited Debug Console output after adding NSLog per Phillip Mills's post.**

```
-[ViewController catagoryFieldPressed:] [line 223] Catagory button
-[CatagoryTableViewController init] [line 18] 
-[CatagoryTableViewController init] [line 21] in here
-[CatagoryTableViewController init] [line 23] 
-[CatagoryTableViewController loadView] [line 171] load view
2012-06-04 18:52:57.930 Fluent[1835:f803] Opened database
2012-06-04 18:52:57.930 Fluent[1835:f803] Path: /Users/sean/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/8B93174F-8836-4533-BCFF-F98AC2F34F26/Documents/fluent_tr.sqlite
-[WordService getCatagories] [line 114] 
-[CatagoryTableViewController itemsInSection:] [line 46] 
(edited repeating NSLogs to shorten)
-[CatagoryTableViewController firstLetter:] [line 39] 
-[CatagoryTableViewController numberOfSectionsInTableView:] [line 99] 
-[CatagoryTableViewController tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:] [line 86] 
-[CatagoryTableViewController firstLetter:] [line 39] 
-[CatagoryTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] [line 108] 
2012-06-04 18:52:57.937 Fluent[1835:f803] Rows per section count: 1
-[CatagoryTableViewController viewDidLoad] [line 31] 
2012-06-04 18:52:57.938 Fluent[1835:f803] Controller: <CatagoryTableViewController: 0x884c880>, View: <UITableView: 0xbb90a00; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x884ce20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
-[ViewController catagoryFieldPressed:] [line 228] Returned from Catagory button
-[ViewController textFieldShouldBeginEditing:] [line 33]
```

**Before AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *numberTestViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NumberTestViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    nav.tabBarItem.title = @"Words";
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController,numberTestViewController, nil];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**After AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    NumberTestViewController *numberTestViewController = [[NumberTestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NumberTestViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav,numberTestViewController, nil];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Does **anything** visual happen when you push the view controller?  Do you see other methods trigger if you insert something like `NSLog(@"Controller: %@, View: %@", childView, childView.view);` just before the push?

Comment: Nothing visual happens when the view controller is pushed. Your NSLog is very useful: when I add it it shows the flow of control through all the relevant methods. I think there is a problem with my section array as zero sections are being returned. Any idea why the Log statements would not work under these circumstances?

Comment: Additional Logs added after insertion of the NSLog.

Comment: Check the value of `self.navigationController` when you do the push...I'm suspicious it may be nil.  The log statement forced loading of the view by referencing it, which the push **should** have done.

Comment: Added this to just before the push: `NSLog(@"Nav Controller: %@",self.navigationController);` Getting no output. Cannot see `self.navigationController` in the variable list.

Comment: Update. The app consists of 2 primary view controllers in a tab bar. The view controllers were instantiated in the AppDelegate using their own class names. When I instantiated as UIViewController the `  NSLog(@"Nav Controller: %@",self.navigationController);` log does indeed produce `Nav Controller: (null)`. AppDelegate.m code posted above. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: OK I found it! Check out the before & after AppDelegate.m. I can created the UINavigationController but not added to `self.tabBarController`. Phew! Thanks a lot Phillip: if you want to add that as the answer I'll vote you up. Sean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, with help from Phillip Mills. The view controller which was calling the UITableView was not correctly added to the navigation stack. It had been instantiated, and then added to the navigationController via `UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];` but the navigation controller itself was not correctly added to the tabBarController.

See the before and after versions of the AppDelegate.m above.

Thanks for your help Phillip.

Comment: Glad you found it.  The debugging trick of explicitly referencing the controller's view to force a load and isolate what part of the process has gone wrong has been useful a number of times.